# Product colorize with a texture image (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use product colorize from nikorablin but in his script use rgb colors and i want to use img (textures) 
Here is the script

```
/*
 * productColorizer - jQuery Plugin
 * version: 1.2 October 2012
 * @requires jQuery v1.6 or later
 *
 * Examples at http://nikorablin.com/sandbox/productColorizer/
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 */
(function($){
    $.fn.productColorizer = function(options) {

        // defaults
        var defaults = {  
            transparency: 0.55,
            swatchTransparency: 0.75,
            secondaryTransparency: 0.55,
            swatchClass: '.swatch'
        };
        // extend defaults
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

            // init objects
            var o = options;
            var obj = $(this);
            var swatch = obj.find(o.swatchClass);
            var swatches = obj.find(o.swatchClass + " a");
            var mask = obj.find('.mask');

            // set swatch colors with the rel values
            $(swatches).each(function(){
                var color = "rgba(" + $(this).attr('rel') + "," + o.swatchTransparency + ")";
                $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
                $(this).find('span').css('background', color);
                if($.browser.msie) {
                    color = $(this).attr('rel');
                    var colors = color.split(",");
                    color = "#" + colorToHex(colors);
                    $(this).find('span').css({'background-color': color});
                }
            });

            // set background color of mask with rel values and transparency
            $(swatches).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(swatches).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var color = "rgba(" + $(this).attr('rel') + "," + o.transparency + ")";
                var mask = $(this).attr('href');
                if($(mask).attr('role')) {
                    $(mask).empty();
                    var R = Raphael(mask.substring(1), $(mask).width(), $(mask).height());
                    var style = {
                        fill: "rgb(" + $(this).attr('rel') + ")",
                        opacity: o.secondaryTransparency,
                        "stroke-width": 0
                    };
                    R.path($(mask).attr('role')).attr(style);
                } else {
                    $(mask).css({"background-color": color}, 1000);
                    if($.browser.msie) {
                        color = $(this).attr('rel');
                        var colors = color.split(",");
                        color = colorToHex(colors);
                        $(mask).css({'background': 'transparent', 'zoom': 1, 'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80' + color + ',endColorstr=#80' + color + ')'});
                    }
                }
            });

            // create tooltips showing color name on swatch hover
            $(swatches).hover(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var offsetX = $(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().offset().left;
                var offsetY = $(this).offset().top - $(this).parent().offset().top + 25;
                var text = $(this).attr('title');
                if(!$.browser.msie) $(this).removeAttr('title');
                $(this).after('<div class="colorizer-tooltip"><div class="colorizer-pointer-up"><div class="colorizer-pointer-up-inner"></div></div><span class="colorizer-tooltip-text">' + text + '</span></div>');
                var offsetToolTip = ($('.colorizer-tooltip').width()/2)-12;
                $('.colorizer-tooltip').css({'left': offsetX-offsetToolTip, 'top':offsetY});
            }, function() {
                var text = $('.colorizer-tooltip-text').html();
                $(this).attr('title', text);
                $(".colorizer-tooltip").remove();
            });

            //rgb to hex
            function colorToHex(color) {

                var red = parseInt(color[0]);
                var green = parseInt(color[1]);
                var blue = parseInt(color[2]);

                var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
                return rgb.toString(16);
            };

        });

    }
})(jQuery);
```

and html

```
<a rel="255,211,8" href="#mask" title="Yellow">Yellow</a>
```

I want to use something like this

```
<a rel="http://www.ex.etc/img.jpg" href="#mask" title="ImgTexture">Img</a> (example how i want to use)
Or with <a rel="img_src" href="htttp://etc.etc/img.jpg" alt="#mask" title="imgtexture"></a>
```

I am newbie at propgraming .. how i have to change the jquery ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Download [archive](https://github.com/nikorablin/productColorizer/tarball/master) with all js and css files.

Add them to you HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.productColorizer.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.productColorizer.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.product').productColorizer();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="swatch">
                <a rel="32,223,95" href="#mask" title="Green">Green</a>
                <a rel="255,211,8" href="#mask" title="Yellow">Yellow</a>
                <a rel="255,101,8" href="#mask" title="Orange">Orange</a>
                <a rel="16,200,255" href="#mask" title="Blue">Blue</a>
                <a rel="142,8,255" href="#mask" title="Purple">Purple</a>
                <a rel="245,25,45" href="#mask" title="Red">Red</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As shown here:

[image]

And you will see the result:

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer but i want to use textures images  instead of colors .. something like  https://www.google.ro/search?q=textures&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx-IKDr5PMAhXJliwKHQYSCs0Q_AUIBygB&biw=1024&bih=736#imgrc=1nr0AVVs1HqibM%3A